# Use nuspec version information from custom target

Tags: msbuild, dotnet-cli, nuspec

I'm trying to use the dotnet CLI to pack and publish packages for one of our solutions. I've created a target to do this so that each project in the solution can use it. The target looks like this:

```xml
<Target Name="PackAndPublishPackages" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' And '$(IsDesignTimeBuild)' != 'false' ">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <NuspecFile>$(MSBuildProjectName).nuspec</NuspecFile> 
        <NuspecProperties>Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform)</NuspecProperties>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Exec Command="del $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(PackageOutputPath)*.nupkg" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet pack $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(MSBuildProjectName).csproj --no-build" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet nuget push $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(PackageOutputPath)*.nupkg -k key -s http://url/" />
</Target>
```

The target runs as I would expect each time, but it doesn't appear to use the version information from the provided nuspec file or the listed nuspec properties defined in the property group when running *dotnet pack*. I've confirmed that the file exists in the directory for each project.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the PropertyGroup at the scope of your target, which only set the property when the target runs.

Did you try to move it outside of the target?

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <NuspecFile>$(MSBuildProjectName).nuspec</NuspecFile> 
  <NuspecProperties>Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform</NuspecProperties>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- later in your csproj -->

<Target Name="PackAndPublishPackages" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' And '$(IsDesignTimeBuild)' != 'false' ">
  <Exec Command="del $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(PackageOutputPath)*.nupkg" />
  <Exec Command="dotnet pack $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(MSBuildProjectName).csproj --no-build" />
  <Exec Command="dotnet nuget push $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(PackageOutputPath)*.nupkg -k key -s http://url/" />
</Target>
```

Comment: jpruee, was it helpful?